# Who deserves credit for simple activation function in ANNs

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, references, history

McCulloch and Pitts (43) are often credited with inventing the Binary Threshold Unit later used in the Perceptron. Who first came up with linear/sigmoid/tanh units?